# Relation between Killing form and its analogues in any other representation

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

For a semisimple compact Lie algebra
\begin{eqnarray}
[T_a,T_b]=if_{ab}^cT_c, 
\end{eqnarray}
the Killing form component takes the form as
\begin{eqnarray}
\kappa_{ab}=-\text{Tr}\left[T_a^AT_b^A\right]=-\left(T_a^A\right)_k^l\left(T_b^A\right)_l^k
\end{eqnarray}
where ''$A$'' means the adjoint representation
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(T_a^A\right)_b^c\equiv-if_{ab}^c. 
\end{eqnarray}
In many textbooks, it is directly given that, for any other representation ''$R$'', an analogue of $\kappa_{ab}$ defined by
\begin{eqnarray}
\kappa_{ab}^R\equiv-\text{Tr}\left[T_a^RT_b^R\right]\propto\kappa_{ab}. 
\end{eqnarray}
I cannot obtain the proportionality above.

Could someone help me reach it and understand it?

Comment: I am seemed to have solved it by myself, and I somehow prove that the tensor product of two adjoint representations has unique invariant which is the Killing form.

Comment: This proportionality should not hold unless the Lie algebra is simple.